# Parse PDF/DOC Bank Statement through PHP

Tags: php, parsing, pdf, doc

I am working on a accouting application. The user will upload the desired pdf or doc bank statement in the application. I need to read/parse the document and insert the amount/cheque number etc...(according to my database structure) in the database.

Please help in achieving the same.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Opening .doc or .pdf files? Parsing the extracted text? Have you tried anything?

Comment: You need to be aware that this is a *massive*, non-trivial task that will require lots of work, and may never reach full automation. Also as @deceze says there are several issues here that you need to split the question up into

Comment: I have not tried anything, I just need a way to start

Comment: 1) Try to extract the contents of the files. 2) Parse them. Come back if you have more concrete problems and **have already tried something but failed.**

Answer (score 0):

PDF is made for representation, not to work with the data inside.

You might be lucky with `pdftotext` or `catdoc`.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this same issue for over 2 weeks now and I have to say it is quite a task. I have had some success finding a php class to extract the text , but the problem is it will not work on every version of the .pdf format it's hit and miss. And drumming one up yourself will take awhile figuring out the encoding and compression issues. Right now I'm actually looking at some python libraries. It's just too time consuming for me to write one of these up from scratch for now.

Comment: Which python libraries were you looking at? Were they of any help?